# File won't upload in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, iis

I have php setup on IIS and trying to implement file upload within CakePHP.

I have followed necessary guidelines for file upload but each time I upload, I keep getting the below with an `uploadError`. What can be wrong as even the `temp_name` is empty.

Initially thought IIS didn't have write permission to the temporary folder but it didn't work even after given full rights to `IIS_IUSRS` and `IUSR`

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(14) "DSC02474_2.JPG"
  ["type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["error"]=>
  int(1)
  ["size"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

**FORM**

```
<?php 
  echo $this->Form->create('User', array('class'=>'form-horizontal', 'action'=>'uploadProfilePicture', 'id'=>'change-picture', 'type'=>'file'));
  echo $this->Form->input('id', array('value'=>$authUser['id']));
  echo $this->Form->file('picture');
?>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-info" name="submit">
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

**HANDLER IN MODEL**

```
public function uploadFile( $check ) {

    $uploadData = array_shift($check);
    if ( $uploadData['size'] == 0 || $uploadData['error'] !== 0) {
        return false;
    }

    $uploadFolder = APP.'uploads'.DS."profile-pictures";
      $fileName = time()."_".$uploadData['name'];
    $uploadPath =  $uploadFolder . DS . $fileName;

    if( !file_exists($uploadFolder) ){
        mkdir($uploadFolder);
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($uploadData['tmp_name'], $uploadPath)) {
        $this->set('picture', $fileName);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code you are using for the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution to my problem on http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php.

If your $_FILES and $_POST are empty, this can be due to

- the limit set by post_max_size in php.ini
- the limit set by upload_max_filesize in php.ini

Unfortunately the first limit is not reported back as an error code in $_FILES['error'].

Comment: You could also get empty `$_FILES` if you forget to declare the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form, like i did.